# XAML Bind control property to assigned style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What I want to achieve is, to create a style for a TextBlock Control which scales in height on mouseover depending on the amount of items which are being hold by the TextBlock.
My approach is to take the item amount and pass it to a converter which gives returns the TextBlock.Height * items.count but I'm having troubles achieving this. 
Also I want this style to only trigger for one column of my ListView and not for all but I haven't thought about how to do that yet.
Currently my XAML code looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SwItemToPopulate}" Name="lvSoftware" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10" MinHeight="325" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Height">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding 
                            Path="Dependencies.Count"
                            Converter="{StaticResource ItemCountToTextBoxHeightConverter}"
                            ConverterParameter="TextBlock.Height" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Dependencies">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Dependencies}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

and this is my converter:

```
namespace test.Converter
{
class ItemCountToTextBoxHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(double))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be an Integer"); 

        int tbHeight = (int)parameter;
        return (Double)value * tbHeight;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
}
```

If I set a Brakepoint to the Converter I can see that the value parameter is 0 and the parameter is TextBlock.Height is this because my binding is wrong or is this not even possible what I'm trying to do?

**Edit** 
I'm using a Tooltip now to achieve this. Thank all for the great comments and answers!

Comment: im not sure the behavior you describe will work as an interface. What happens if you move your mouse over the first listitem, and that entry has 100 dependencies. So it's height grows to 100x. Now how do you get to the second item? If you move your mouse down just below the first item, ie 100x + 1 that immediately causes the first item to collapse to 1x again. Which means the second item is now far above where the mouse is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBlock` isn't designed to handle this scenario. You should use [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead.

Changing the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` to a `ItemsControl` would achieve this.

Having said that, try using `TextBlock.ActualHeight` and not `Height`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using an ItemsControl now and the value parameter is now being passed to the converter but the ConverterParameter is still not working. Any idea?

Comment: I've edited my answer; give it a go and let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually, changing the `ConverterParameter` value to `{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}` isn't going to work in this case. I'm unsure how to access the `TextBlock`. Perhaps displaying the content in a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) is a better strategy?

Comment: ConverterParameter cannot bind to any property since it is not dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the property trigger so that it instead resets the item to the normal height when the mouse isn't over and therefore textblock height can be bound to Dependency.Count. I have hardcoded the normal heights as 20 because I wasn't sure how else to do it.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dependencies">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Dependencies}" 
                                    Height="{Binding Path=Dependencies.Count, Converter={StaticResource ItemCountToTextBoxHeightConverter}, ConverterParameter=20}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```